# Property method in python not returning correct value

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators

I am trying to solve the question in which I am asked to use property method to count the number of times the circles are created . Below is the code for the same.

```
import os
import sys

#Add Circle class implementation below
class Circle:
    counter = 0
    def __init__(self,radius):
        self.radius = radius
        Circle.counter = Circle.counter + 1
        
    def area(self):
        return self.radius*self.radius*3.14
    
    def counters():
        print(Circle.counter)
    no_of_circles = property(counter)
      


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
        res_lst = list()
        lst = list(map(lambda x: float(x.strip()), input().split(',')))
        
        for radius in lst:
            res_lst.append(Circle(radius).area())
        
        print(str(res_lst), str(Circle.no_of_circles))
```

The above code gives correct output for the area but counter should be 3 and instead I am getting below output . Below is the output for input = 1,2,3

```
[3.14, 12.56, 28.26] <property object at 0x0000024AB3234D60>
```

I have tried everything but no luck. In the main section of the code no_of_circles is called as Circle.no_of_circles which suggests me that it will use property method of python. But the output is wrong. Please help me find where I am going wrong.

Comment: Why do you need `no_of_circles` separately from `counter`? The `property` decorator is meant to make a method look like an attribute, so you can use the syntax for an attribute. But `counter` is already an attribute so it can already be accessed using the syntax for an attribute.

Comment: @kaya3 if I don't use no_of_circles then how do I set property decorator . The main section of code will not change. Can you edit the code and tell me where do I need to make changes?

Answer (score 0):

`str(Circle.no_of_circles)` here you're calling the property of a class not an instance of that class i.e a Circle object; the following will work :-

```py
class Circle:
    counter = 0
    def __init__(self,radius):
        self.radius = radius
        Circle.counter = Circle.counter + 1

    def area(self):
        return self.radius*self.radius*3.14

    def counters():
        print(Circle.counter)
    no_of_circles = property(counter)

if __name__ == "__main__":
        lst = list(map(lambda x: float(x.strip()), input("Enter radius : ").split(',')))
        cir_lst = [Circle(_) for _ in lst]
        res_lst = [__.area() for __ in cir_lst]

        print(res_lst, cir_lst[-1].counter)
```

Comment: @Programming-in-Python the question does not allow me to edit the main section of the code. So what I need to edit to make it work without touching the main section?

Comment: @isilia Try it now...

Comment: @Programming-in-python .its working now . We don't even need counters function. If we remove counters function and just keep line - property(counter) - and the output just was fine. Can you try the same and let me know the reason for this behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple working example using the `property` function.
Note: It is always a good practice to make an instance of a class(once) and then uses the instance all over your code. Also better to use `self.counter` instead of `Cirlcle.counter`. self is Circle.

```py
#Add Circle class implementation below
class Circle:
    
    def __init__(self,value=0):
        self._counter = value
        
    def area(self, radius):
        return radius*radius*3.14
    
    def add_counter(self, value):
        print('add counter')
        self._counter += 1

    def get_counter(self):
        print('get counter')
        return self._counter

    no_of_circles = property(get_counter, add_counter)
      


if __name__ == "__main__":
    circle = Circle()
    area = []
    for idx in range(5):
        area.append(circle.area(idx))
        circle.add_counter(1)
    print("number of calls: ", circle.no_of_circles)
    print('area:', area)
```

output(note how get and add counter are called):

```py
add counter
add counter
add counter
add counter
add counter
get counter
number of calls:  5
area: [0.0, 3.14, 12.56, 28.26, 50.24]
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation, but in my question I can't change the code in the __main__ section  It means I can't create the instance. Now can you get the same output without creating instance. I mean in my question that is the original code ..why Circle.no_of_circles is not working ? and how will it work. All the code that can change and tweak is above the __main__ section .